# Server/Android client receives/sends only once

Tags: java, sockets

I wanted to send a string of text from my android phone over to a Java server running on my PC and it works but only once, it would receive the first string but when I type in another one on my phone and I press the button, the server doesn't receive anything, (here is my code for the android app):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            messsage = etMsg.getText().toString();
            etMsg.setText("");

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try
                    {
                        client = new Socket(etIP.getText().toString(), port);
                        printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                        printwriter.write(messsage);
                        printwriter.flush();
                        printwriter.close();
                        client.close();
                    }
                    catch (UnknownHostException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

And here is the code for the Java server:

```
package src;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VRS {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        System.out.println("server started on port 4444");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    }catch(Exception e){} //read & display the message
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputS­tream()));
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        String mes; 
        while(true){
            if (in1.hasNext())
            {
                mes=in1.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Client message :"+mes + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me find the problem as I'm a beginner in terms of Java.

Answer (score 0):

The scanner on the server is waiting for a complete token with a terminator and you are not sending one from the client. Try appending a line terminating character on the client side e.g.

```
printwriter.println(messsage);
```

In addition to that it seems that for every click on the client side a new `Socket` object is created. But the server is not waiting for a new connection. You can either :

1. reuse the `Socket` on the client side instead of creating a new one for every click. e.g. make your `client` variable a class member.
2. On the server side after each message call `clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();` again to create a new `Socket`. This new server side `Socket` will correspond to the new Socket on the client.

The first option is considered more efficient especially as the number of connections and messages you want to handle increases.

Comment: Tried that and still only does it once :(

Comment: @user265889 There seems to be one more issue. I have updated the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "Make your client" a variable class? I also tried to create a new boolean that gets set to false the first time it connects but the second time it just says connection refused :/

Comment: The `Socket client` variable that is apparently declared somewhere else in your code. You are constructing a new one each time `onClick` function is called with this line `client = new Socket(etIP.getText().toString(), port);`. That results in a new attempt to connect to the server. But the server has accepted the first connection and is no longer listening for new ones.

Comment: Yes in the beginning of my code it states: Private socket client; How would i reuse the existing connection for a second string?

Comment: Try at the beginning of your code : `private Socket client = new Socket(etIP.getText().toString(), port);` so that you reuse this object instead of making a new one in `OnClick()`

Comment: So I added it to the beginning of my code when it first starts, but when I press the button a second time it says the socket is closed even after I removed client.close();